# Are there any background walls which are immune to explosives?

Tags: terraria

Explosives are powerful. Maybe a little too powerful for my liking.

I've set up a trap where mobs fall into a pit of explosive proof material (in this case, mythril ore), where I'm free to throw dynamite or bombs to my heart's content.

However, I want there to be a background wall so that mobs won't spawn inside the pit while it's closed off (using active/inactive stone blocks).

So far all my attempts have failed with the background being blown clean off the sky.

Is there a wall that will remain in place even if dynamite goes off right in front of it?

Comment: Have you tried Dungeon Brick Walls? I *think* they're dynamite-proof, but I'm in no position to verify this for myself.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I gave Green Dungeon Brick walls a go after posting this question, but they broke too. I'm wondering if hellstone walls will work, but even if they do, I'll have to map edit them into my trap :(

Comment: Maybe just use bombs instead of dynamite? SLower, but if it doesn't break the walls...

Comment: @RavenDreamer Bombs have been upgraded to work exactly the same way as dynamite, just less damage and blast radius. They still break the same blocks.

Comment: There's always grenades and magic!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is **no**. The only background walls completely impervious to anything are world-generated, unsafe walls (unless the blast reaches a hole in the wall, or an edge). However, these, by design, cannot be placed by the player at all, and in any case do not prevent monster spawns.

It looks like you're out of luck here. Bombs and Dynamite can blow up any player-placed wall.

Comment: Actually, I just had some natural dirt walls ripped off by a clown bomb, so I think even natural walls are not immune to explosives.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried either Cobalt or Mythril brick walls? I'm pretty sure those are the hardest things in the game so far.

Comment: If you craft the hardmode ores into bricks, they lose their explosion resistance. The background equivalents aren't resistant, either.